# Possible to draw in YCbCr in Java?

Tags: java, video, colors, canvas, rgb

I've a project at the moment, in Java, which uses a filetype which is inherently in the YCbCr colorspace. Within this, there is a lot of number crunching happening behind the scenes (which I've had to code) to convert to RGB from the YCbCr values. This is done per-pixel, per-frame, at 25 frames per second...

The project must be entirely written in software, and must be platform independant.

If I could skip this step, and still create an image from an array, but in a YCbCr format, I could save a lot of work...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably do this with the [ColorSpace](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/color/package-frame.html) class. I would be surprised if you needed to convert each YCbCr value individually. I'm sure the [java.awt.image](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/package-frame.html) package will provide classes for handling this. You may find something in Chapter 5 of [Java Advanced Imaging](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai1_0_1guide-unc/JAITOC.fm.html).

Answer (score 3):

Building on McDowell's answer, [this](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai1_0_1guide-unc/Color.doc.html#51551) seems to be of interest, it explains how to do a colorspace conversion.